# Aerospike read times out before max retries is reached

Tags: aerospike

I have the following config for aerospike read policy:

```
clientPolicy.timeout = 200; // timeout for refreshing cluster status, shouldn't affect reads
clientPolicy.readPolicyDefault.socketTimeout = 30;
clientPolicy.readPolicyDefault.totalTimeout = 110;
clientPolicy.readPolicyDefault.maxRetries = 2;
clientPolicy.readPolicyDefault.sleepBetweenRetries = 0;
```

According to what I found in Aerospike docs this should result in 3 read attempts 30ms max for each  (1 initial + 2 retries), which in total is 90 ms and it is less than total timeout of 110 ms.
But in application logs I see timeout exceptions after 1 retry:

```
org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: Client timeout: iteration=1 connect=0 socket=30 total=110 maxRetries=2 node= inDoubt=false; 
nested exception is com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException$Timeout: Client timeout: iteration=1 connect=0 socket=30 total=110 maxRetries=2 node= inDoubt=false
...
Caused by: com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException$Timeout: Client timeout: iteration=1 connect=0 socket=30 total=110 maxRetries=2 node= inDoubt=false
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Maybe there are more actions that occur and are included in this total timeout?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like to me you don't have a connection to a node. Try with clientPolicy.timeout = 1000 (default).  You may have timed out in trying to establish an initial connection to a node.

Comment: I believe the clientPolicy.timeout is for the tend thread only. There should be a connectTimeout or connectionTimeout for the time spent establishing a new connection (for connections other than the tend thread connection).

Comment: connectTimeout - default is 0.  Looks like there is no node info. "node= " . "inDoubt=False" ...so nothing was written to the server node.

Comment: @pgupta thanks, I'll try. As for the node info - there are node IPs in exception logs, I removed them from exception to be safe. However I also noticed that some exceptions are with "node=null" in the message, so your point is valid anyway

Comment: there is clientPolicy.readPolicyDefault.connectTimeout config which defaults to 0, maybe this is what I need to look into?

Comment: 0 means do not use connectTImeout to  timeout when waiting to open the connection (socket) to send the transaction. Then, it will use socketTimeout or totalTImeout to establish the connection (30 & 100 ms) in your case or timeout.  Try setting connectTimeout to 1000 ms since your socketTimeout and totalTimeout are rather small values.  (Not recall right now which it will use 30 or 100, my guess is 30 in this case. ) Did you also try increasing tend thread timeout from 200 to 1000ms?

Comment: @pgupta today I applied updated timeouts, tend thread timeout (clientPolicy.timeout) now has default value, and I've set clientPolicy.readPolicyDefault.connectTimeout to 200ms. But I still encounter such errors from time to time, max retries are not reached:

org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: Client timeout: iteration=1 connect=200 socket=30 total=110 maxRetries=2 node=A0 <ip> 3000 inDoubt=false; nested exception is com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException$Timeout: Client timeout: iteration=1 connect=200 socket=30 total=110 maxRetries=2 node=A0 <ip> 3000 inDoubt=false

Comment: do you think that setting 1s to clientPolicy.readPolicyDefault.connectTimeout will help? I actually expect my service to respond pretty quickly and cannot afford waiting so long

Comment: @pgupta I added 1s connect timeout but it seems like aerospike is not using it, it's taking totalTimeout which is less than 1 second

Comment: Does this response close your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008064/aerospike-connect-timeout-works-incorrectly

Comment: looks like it explains the problem, however I'm not sure what to do with it. I still observe such exceptions